# Select exact expiry date

Tags: mysql

I have this record in `expiry_date` column:

```
2015-04-30 04:15:29
2015-04-22 06:02:07
```

I need to select where the record is `26` days from expiring. Right now I'm using this which is not working. No records were selected.

```
SELECT * FROM `client` WHERE `expiry_date` = DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 26 DAY)
```

I've searched this website and many of the answers are using `<=` operator. This solution partially work. It selects `both` of my record when I only need `2015-04-30 04:15:29` in `expiry_date` column.

How do I exactly select date that is going to expired and not all date?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easy solution to this is to use the `date` function:

```
WHERE DATE(expiry_date) = DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL 26 DAY)
```

However, this prevents the use of an index on `expiry_date`.  An alternative that does work with indexes is:

```
WHERE expiry_date >= DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL 26 DAY) AND
      expiry_date < DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL 26 + 1 DAY)
```

Comment: Hi, the first one does work thank you very much but the second one didn't. I prefer to use index but I only get empty result. BTW is that a typo with `INTERVAL 26  1 DAY`?

Comment: @sg552 . . . There should have been (and now is) a `+` in the expression.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you're having this issue is that expiry_date is a type of datetime so the time makes it not equal.  Just change your code to be:

```
SELECT * FROM client WHERE DATE(expiry_date) = DATE(DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 26 DAY))
```